# Where do the Puranas describe Krishna fighting suitors after marrying Nagnajiti?

Tags: puranas, krishna, identification-request, arjuna

The incident I am talking about is this:

> Finally, Krishna and Nagnajiti departed towards Dwarka, accompanied by their army to protect them. On this way, they were attacked by the princes who had lost in Nagnajit's bull challenge. Krishna's army yielded by his Yadava clan warriors and his friend Arjuna defeated the princes and chased them away.

Source- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagnajiti)

Also, from [Quora](https://www.quora.com/in/Who-was-was-a-better-warrior-Bhisma-or-Arjuna):

> When Lord Krishna married Nagnajiti, many unsuccessful suitors of royal lineage attacked Krishna. Arjuna defeated all of them single handedly without killing them, on Krishna’s orders.

My question is- In which section of the Puranas is this incident found?

Comment: We didn't quote the sections of Purana. Quora answerer did. So, you should ask the answerer there. Did you try that? Wikipedia didn't mention any claim. Ask question properly. This is not a forum where question title is everything. [edit] the question more clearly and properly.

Comment: @@Thelogical Is my edit good? Is this what ur question is? if not pls edit it again accordingly.

Comment: @sarva.. Read the wiki link.. the first BQ in this Q is as per Bhagavata Purana.. and OP wants to know where exactly in that Purana is this story found..

Comment: @Rickross See the reason I gave while I edited the question.  What is given in the question is important for us. We should edit based on what is quoted in the question body or title.and not in the total wikipedia article. Why not add Vishnu Purana, Harivamsha etc. If you consider whole wiki while editing, you will probably add answer in the edit.

Comment: Yes and the Q only linked that wiki page..the quote is from Bhagavata Purana as per wiki.. OP is asking where in that Purana is it found ? what is this useless editing going on? @Sarvabhouma

Comment: @Rickross Does *the OP say that the quote is from the Bhagavata only* anywhere in the body? You should edit and tag based on the body. Don't edit with what what you have found in the wiki article. It should be in the answer. The edit you made should be in the answer.

Comment: Wiki says that the 1st BQ is from Bhagavata Purana.. and OP quotes from that Wiki page which says so..and then asks where in that Purana.. so what's in this? @Sarvabhouma

Comment: Wiki does not say which chapter..it only says which Purana..so how can it be the answer?? @Sarvabhouma anyways do as u wish

Comment: @Rickross Wiki not only says Bhagavatam, it says total verse. Did you check the references for the quote OP added? It adds references to Bhagavatam Dashama Skandha along with verse number. Now, will you edit Which shloka of 10.58 has this verse? If you add Bhagavata in the question, the question itself is dead. Your edit itself should have been an answer.

Comment: @Rickross Wikipedia may know it's from the Bhagavatam, but the OP is not evincing knowledge that it's from the Bhagavatam.  So we shouldn't edit the question with Bhagavatam.

Comment: Sarvabhouma Quora usually bans people from their site, and most people dont have an account for it.

Answer (score 5):

The story of Krishna's marriage with Nagnajiti is present in the fifty-eighth chapter of the tenth canto of the Bhagavata Purana:

> O King, Nagnajit, the very pious King of Kośala, had a lovely daughter named Satyā, or **Nāgnajitī**. (Bhagavata Purana 10.58.32)

---

> When the intolerant kings who had been rival suitors heard what had happened, **they tried to stop Lord Kṛṣṇa on the road as He took His bride home.** But just as the bulls had broken the kings’ strength before, the Yadu warriors broke it now. **Arjuna, wielder of the Gāṇḍīva bow, was always eager to please his friend Kṛṣṇa, and thus he drove back those opponents, who were shooting torrents of arrows at the Lord. He did this just as a lion drives away insignificant animals.** (Bhagavata Purana 10.58.53-54)

You can read the complete story [here](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/58).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the best description is found in the **[Harivamsa Southern Recension](http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/southern/12_utf.html)** in which 'Krsnasya Nilaya Saha Vivahah' chapter (marriage of Krsna with Nila Devi) ends with  Krishna fighting suitors after marrying Nila (Nagnajiti). And according to the South Indian Versions (which I think are the most unadulterated scriptures), the newlyweds did not go to Dwarka instead they went to Vrindaban and stayed there for the entire winter.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange. Is there any English translation available for the cited link?

Comment: Thanks for your question @hanugm, I feel honored that a person of your callibre and reputation has asked this question. 
 Yes, I will search the exact English reference. I have read it in Hindi & Sanskrit in Bhagwat Puran, Tenth Canto, Chapter 58, Shloka 41-55 (श्रीमद्भागवत महापुराण: दशम स्कन्ध: अष्टपञ्चाशत्त्मोऽध्यायः श्लोक 41-55) which gives the most detailed version of Lord Krishna and Arjun fighting suitors of Princes Nagnajiti after marrying her during the return journey.